# How to save elements that uses my annotation?

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing

I use the method `process()`, from class that inherits from `AbstractProcessor`, to get the names of elements that use my annotation.

How to save a list of that names, so that I can use them in my eg. `main()` method?

@edit I have a class `ClassList` that will store the names of classes that use the annotation `@CustomAnnotation`

```
public class ClassList {
    private static final List<String> classList= new LinkedList<>();

    public static List<String> getClassList() {
        return classList;
    }

    public static void addList(String name) {
        classList.add(name);
    }
}
```

Here I have the interface @CustomAnnotation

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CustomAnnotation{

}
```

Here is the implementation of the class that will process the annotations

```
@SupportedAnnotationTypes("com.example.CustomAnnotation")
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_8)
public class CompileTimeAnnotationProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations,
            RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        Set<? extends Element> elements = roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(CustomAnnotation.class);
        for (Element e : elements) {
            //adds each name to the list
            ClassList.addList(e.getSimpleName().toString());
        }
        //prints the array 
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ClassList.getClassList().toArray(new String[ClassList.getClassList().size()])));
        return true;
    }

}
```

Then I use the annotation

```
@CustomAnnotation
public class AnnotatedClass {

}
@CustomAnnotation
public class TestClass {

}
```

Now when I have the `main()` method I would like to access that classes.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(ClassList.getClassList().size());
}
```

When I clean and build it indeed prints the array in the method `process()`, but then i run the main program the list is empty. How to access that list in the main program?

Comment: Your question is not clear at all.Edit it with more details of your actual code and what  you want to achieve.

Comment: Please try to elaborate your questions, add more code or give us more context

Comment: Ok I edited my post with some code

Answer (score 2):

The annotation processing is happening at compilation time. You have to preserve that information until run time. The only way to do that is writing it to some permanent storage (e.g. application resources).

1. Give your annotations at least `RetentionPolycy.CLASS`, just in case.
2. In every compilation round perform search for new annotated elements and add their names to a Set, like your already do (hint: storing `Name` instances works just as fine).
3. During the last compilation round write contents of that Set to some resource file (you can find example of annotation processor, that generates resource files, in Google's [Auto](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/service) library).
4. Read the resource file inside your application's main method

Answer (score 2):

As [user1643723](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1643723/user1643723) said, the processor needs to create a resource file at compilation time, which your application can then read at runtime. Here is an example based on your code.

To create a resource, you need to use the `Filer` which is provided by the processors `processingEnv`. This will create a file in the class base directory:

```
Filer filer = processingEnv.getFiler();
FileObject resource = filer.createResource(StandardLocation.CLASS_OUTPUT, "", "classnames.txt", (Element[]) null);
Writer writer = resource.openWriter();
for (String className : ClassList.getClassList()) {
    writer.write(className);
    writer.write("\n");
}
writer.close();
```

Now you can load it in your application, like any other resource.

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/classnames.txt");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
reader.close();
```